# My Redux Store Updates, the Props in the Components have been updatet too but the Component doesnt rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a Redux that worked fine until I normalized the Data, now i have 2 Arrays as Store.

Wrote another Reducers, combined them.

When I dispatch an Action the Reducers working fine and returning the correct new values.

The Store is updatet, the Props in the Child Compnents as well in the App Container Component are updatet too.
But the Component do not recognize the Prop changes.(they dont go in willReceiveProps)

But in the react-developer tools from google Chrome the Values are correct.

My Reducer:

```
`export default handleActions<any, NodeModel>({
[ADD_NODE]: (state: any, action: Action<NodeModel>): any => {
    let result = [...state, action.payload];

    return result;
},
[MOVE_NODE]: (state: any, action: Action<NodeModel>): any => {
    let result = assign(state)

    Object.keys(result).map((n: any) => {
        result[n].id == action.payload.id ?
            result[n] = action.payload : result[n] = result[n]
    })

    return result;
}
```

}, normalizedStoreData.entities.Nodes);`

My Actions :

```
export const addNode = createAction<NodeModel, NodeModel>(
    ADD_NODE, 
    (node : NodeModel) => node
);

export const moveNode = createAction<NodeModel, NodeModel, number>(
    MOVE_NODE,
    (node : NodeModel, newParentId : number) => {
       let result : NodeModel = assign(node, { ParentId : newParentId})
       return result;
    }   
);
```

App.tsx(App Container):

```
createColumn(Col: any, dispatch: any, key?: any) {
    return (
        <Column
            key={key}
            moveNode={(t: any, s: any) => dispatch(moveNode(t, s))}
            addNode={(t: any) => dispatch(addNode(t))}
            Nodes={getNodes(this.state.data, Col.id)}
            Column={Col} />);
}

createColumns(dispatch: any ){
    let result : any[] = [];
    this.state.data.Columns.map((Col : any) => {
        result.push(this.createColumn(Col, dispatch, Col.id));
    })
    return result;
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps : any){
    console.log(nextProps);
    this.forceUpdate();
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps : any, nextState : any){
    console.log("EDFDF");
    this.forceUpdate();
}


render() {
    const dispatch = this.props.dispatch;
    const data = this.state.data;
    return (
        <div className="container">
          {this.createColumns(dispatch)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: It looks you haven't connected your component with the redux store properly, where does `this.state.data` come from? instead of use `this.state`, you should map store data into `props`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` will shallow compare `props` and `nextProps` to decide if an update is required.

Comment: Sorry have done this for testing
previously i used the props as you say.
But I resetted it, the problem is still the same as before.

`const mapStateToProps = (state : any) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        data: state
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(App))`

Comment: `mapStateToProps` maps store state to `this.props.data`, not `this.state.data`. the `state` in `mapStateToProps` is the whole application state, and `this.state` in your component is a local state, they're different thing.

Comment: yes i know, that happens.
For testing i put the props in the component state.
But i changed it back and use the props now but the views still don´t Update.

Comment: Can you post your full component code please?

Comment: the compnent got too many characters to post so i put it in google drive here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4HXdgpQJmMwaHdCbmJtdDVWMVE

Comment: Component looks okay to me, but when I look into your reducer again, I found this `let result = assign(state)`, does it really clone the state or just assign? `state` needs to be immutable.

Comment: Yes thank you !!
Changed the Reducer Method to this and it worked.
`[MOVE_NODE]: (state: any, action: Action<NodeModel>): any => {
        let result = [...state];

        Object.keys(result).map((n: any) => {
            result[n].id == action.payload.id ?
                result[n] = action.payload : result[n] = result[n]
        })
`